# I can't figure out this function

Tags: function, object, arguments

Create a function that has one argument called **carsArray**.

Inside the function, loop through the **carsArray** argument and console log the *name* property in each object.

Call the function and pass in the ***cars*** variable below.

```
const cars = [
    {
        name: "Toyota",
        horsepower: 100
    },
    {
        name: "Dodge",
        horsepower: 300
    },
    {
        name: "Nissan",
        horespower: 150
    }
];
```

Comment: Hello André, welcome to SO . Please provide your attempt at solving the issue and specify what exactly you're struggling with. (Also tag the language you're using - JS?)

Answer (score 0):

I've assumed you want it in `javascript`.

It's simple, just loop over the array in question, then access the element via `carsArray[i]` then access the name property.

Here's a small video on objects [Youtube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=abP2q8eEXWg)

Here's the code.

```
const cars = [
  {
    name: 'Toyota',
    horsepower: 100
  },
  {
    name: 'Dodge',
    horsepower: 300
  },
  {
    name: 'Nissan',
    horespower: 150
  }
];

function doSomething(carsArray) {
  for (let i = 0; i < carsArray.length; i++) {
    console.log(carsArray[i].name);
  }
}

doSomething(cars);
```